# MySQL GROUP BY Newest on some fields

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Type   UserID    Timestamp    
1     1      1000      1312389223
2     1      1000      1312389220
3     2      1000      1312389215
4     3      1000      1312389213
5     3      2000      1312389205
6     1      2000      1312389201
7     2      1000      1312389190
```

What I need now, is to retrieve only certain parts of the data in this table. The list shows data in relation to what a certain user has been doing on my site.
Some of the "Type"'s need to have all entries shown. Others need only to have the most recent shown.

In the above example I need to have all occurances of Type = 2 shown, but only top 1 (ordered by Timestamp) of Type = 1 shown. Same goes for Type = 3. This is per UserID basis.

Hope I have explained myself clear enough.

Thanks in advance for your help,
fischer.

Comment: What query you have got so far?

Comment: Do you need all these in a single query? Why dont you consider splitting up them?

Comment: They are not needed to be in a single query. I just need it to run as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and quick solution if you dont need IDs

```
select user, type, timestamp from Table where type = 2
union
select user, type, max(timestamp) from Table where type in (1,3) group by user, type
```

That will keep IDs, but it's more complicated and somewhat slower:

```
select * from Table where type = 2
union
select * 
from Table t
join (
    select type, user, max(timestamp) as timestamp
    from Table 
    where type in (1,3)
    group by type, user
) tt on tt.user = t.user and tt.type=t.type and tt.timestamp = t.timestamp
```

Anyway, both solutions are not very scalable

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a look at these. Do you have any idea how I can make a solution which will be scalable?

Comment: Just don't use it in a single query. I think you in your PHP code could have a 'base-query', like $base = 'select * from Table' and than add conditions to it: $base.="where type=2" for type 2 or $base.= "where type=1 and user=1 limit 0,1", etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, 
       type, 
       userid, 
       max(timestamp)
from table
where type in (1, 3)
group by id, type, userid
union
select *
from table
where type = 2
```

Comment: Isn't "group by id, type, userid" will give every record?